# How can I update a column with a sql select condition? (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I have two tables: a and b 
and the following select statement:

```
select a.NAME, a.EMAIL b.NAME, b.YEAR,
from  a, b
where a.NAME = b.NAME
and b.YEAR = 2015;
```

I want to update a.email for each row that the "select" returns.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **MERGE** statement such that your query could be used in the USING clause.

For example,

```
MERGE INTO A t USING
(SELECT a.NAME,
  a.EMAIL b.NAME,
  b.YEAR,
FROM a,
  b
WHERE A.NAME  = b.NAME
AND b.YEAR    = 2015
) s ON(t.NAME = s.NAME)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET t.email = s.email
/
```

Comment: With MERGE, you cannot update the columns that are part of the matching clause (ON ...). So this won't work because of the *email* columns.

Comment: @Codo Yes, thanks for pointing it out. I looked at OP's questions once again.and fortunately, I think the email column is not needed in the ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

Update statement

```
UPDATE a
SET a.email = 'TESTJONAS' 
WHERE a.email = (SELECT a.EMAIL
       FROM a, b
       WHERE a.NAME = b.NAME
       AND b._WJ = 2015)
```

Update statement with joins

```
UPDATE a
SET a.email = 'TESTJONAS'
WHERE a.email = (SELECT a.EMAIL
       FROM a
       INNER JOIN b ON a.NAME = b.NAME
       WHERE b._WJ = 2015)
```

Comment: update a 
set a.EMAIL = 'TESTJONAS'
where (SELECT a.EMAIL 
       FROM  a,b
       WHERE a.NAME = b.NAME 
       AND b._WJ = 2015)
;

I tried it like that. But a get "missing expression" error :/

Comment: thank u. but now i have the following error "single-row subquery returns morge than one row"

Comment: because the sub query is returning more than 1 row, you need to be more specific in your where conditions

Comment: mhh ok, but I want to update all 271 rows the select-statement returns

Comment: yes thats fine, there is no limit to the amount of rows you can update but the rows you update need to be unique#